# Use string or constant for $_SESSION's key?

Tags: php, constants

I have many session vars. Should I use this

```
$_SESSION[SessionHelper::ROUTING] = SessionHelper::MODULE_A;

class SessionHelper {
   const ROUTING = 'SessionHelper.routing';
   const MODULE_A = 1;
   const MODULE_B = 2;
}
```

or this?

```
$_SESSION['routing'] = 1;
```

The first seems to be maintenanable but hard to read in some case. For example:

```
if(isset($_SESSION[SessionHelper::ROUTING]) && 
   $_SESSION[SessionHelper::ROUTING] = SessionHelper::MODULE_A) {
....
```

The second is quite short but if there is a change, we must change everywhere the "routing" exist. Further more, it can pollute the session scope because the 'routing' string is so common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need a session helper (say: if you really need a class abstracting a PHP session), then use the `$_SESSION` superglobal only inside that class (and not outside). So you have the superglobal encapsulated and you can replace it with test-doubles.

Next to that, this depends on the use of the session store. I bet it's highly dynamic, so I don't see much value in specifying array keys as constants first w/o any futher use (e.g. valid/invalid key checks aren't done).

I hope this does not sound harsh, because it's not meant so. Please ask if something is unclear or you have further questions. As jprofitt wrote in his answer, preventing [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) is something very useful, but I'm not totally convinced, that you actually introduce them here or if it isn't just dynamic properties (especially if you create a session store class).

Comment: Is this what you mean? Please let me know.
class SessionStore {
 const ROUTING = 'SessionStore.routing';
 
 public function setRoute($route) {
  $_SESSION[self::ROUTING] = $route;
 }
 
 public function getRoute() {
  return $_SESSION[self::ROUTING];
 }
}

Comment: Something like that could be an example. It is at least encapsulating `$_SESSION`, which was one of the points I mentioned. So yes. Your example has even the benefit, that the rest of the application needs to interface with concrete method names even.

Comment: The last question. Because this class just sets and gets session vars, so could all functions be static? (a utility class)

Comment: All functions *could* be static because `$_SESSION` is "static" (it's a superglobal to be precise). However, don't do that. Make it an instance, avoid static functions and implement the constants (if they are public) in an interface and not inside a concrete class. Regarding sessions, also keep in mind that PHP has a mechanism to change the storage of session variables (before you re-invent the wheel for a session store).

Answer (score 2):

Magic strings and numbers are evil -- even if you're the only one who would need to use them. All it takes is forgetting to update them in one place and your entire application could malfunction.

As you mentioned with the maintainability of using constants, they can make implementing updates a lot simpler. Another benefit is you can document them and a lot of IDEs will pick that up and give help in case you forget what MODULE_A or MODULE_B is referring to (for example). While it might make you type in some extra characters, it's better than misspelling 'routing' somewhere and having to dig through your code to figure out why you're getting an error.